# Auto Dropdown On Load davidstutz bootstrap multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

The select plugin I am using is [David Stutz Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

I am loading the select field through ajax/jquery and it works great but I am struggling to get the select field to initiate the dropdown event on load.

Is this possible to do with this plugin?

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Then it will be easier for others to think about your problem and your chances of a helpful answer will increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little playing about you can do something like this:

```
$('#namehere').multiselect({
        onInitialized: function(select, container) {
            $(container).addClass('open');
        }
});
```